# How to use HibernateTemplate in spring-boot-starter-data-jpa :3.2.1?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-6.x

i find that `HibernateTemplate` can not be rightly loaded in new version.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv5yl.png)

in HibernateTemplate.java , it import the package

> org.hibernate.Criteria

but in `hibernate-core.6.4.1.Final` jar file which comes from spring-boot-starter-data-jpa :3.2.1
i don't find the `org.hibernate.Criteria` file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCKRO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzphK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that hibernate6 has abandoned the use of HibernateTemplate, and recommends using JPA's API, or directly using Session to operate.